# Не читает из баз данных mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Я создал базу и заполнил его с данными, но на экран не выводится. Как правильно установить подключение:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SportsStory;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

или

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\SportsStory.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Я из книги Адама Фримена делаю.

Comment: Что то из этого не работает? Или в чем вопрос?

Comment: Адам Фримен - так вот тот вредитель, что советует людям вписывать AttachDbFilename для (LocalDB)!

Comment: Покажите минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать такую строку:
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SportsStory;Integrated Security=True"